# How do I test if a file is any kind of code, string, or text file? (php)

Tags: php, file, text, file-extension

I am trying to make an if statement to test if a file is editable with a text box, like a .txt or .html, .php, .css, etc.  This is what I have so far.

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo $ext;
     if ($ext == 'html' || $ext == 'php' || $ext == 'css' || $ext == 'js'  || $ext == 'txt') {
       echo 'true';
     } else {
       echo 'false';
     }
```

I want to make the if statement shorter so i don't have to list out tens of file extensions.  Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: use `in_array($ext, [])` on if condition and put all extentions on empty array

Comment: try is_readable()

Comment: is_readable will return true on an image file, it doesn't tell you if it's a plain text file

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

Function in_array will solve your problem Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$extArray= array("html", "php", "css", "js","txt");

if (in_array($ext, $extArray))
  {
  echo 'true';
  }
else
  {
  echo 'false';
  }
```

Comment: i asked if there was a way to make it shorter so that i wouldn't have to list tens of different file extensions.

Comment: As these extensions are of your choice so probably this is the only better way to make if statement shorter

Answer (score 0):

Check the MIME type which will be returned as `text/html`, `text/plain`, `image/png`, etc:

```
$finf = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type = finfo_file($finf, $file);

if(strpos($type, 'text') === 0) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Or:

```
if(strpos(mime_content_type($file), 'text') === 0) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```